# Proof of Iterative Solution for Tower of Hanoi Problem

Tags: puzzle, combinatorial-game-theory

So I was exploring the [Towers of Hanoi problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Iterative_solution) on wikipedia, and I came across the [iterative solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Iterative_solution) of:

1. Make the legal move between pegs A and B (in either direction)
2. Make the legal move between pegs A and C (in either direction),
3. Make the legal move between pegs B and C (in either direction), repeat until complete

for an even number of disks, and for an odd number of disks:

1. Make the legal move between pegs A and C (in either direction)
2. Make the legal move between pegs A and B (in either direction),
3. Make the legal move between pegs B and C (in either direction), repeat until complete.

Why does this iterative solution work? I explored a bit further and discovered that if you continue this set of instructions even when the disks are all on the right pole, the disks will eventually end up in a pile in the middle pole. Why does this happen?

Comment: One approach might be to show this is equivalent to the previous solution *("alternate moves between the smallest piece and a non-smallest piece. When moving the smallest piece, always move it to the next position in the same direction (to the right if the starting number of pieces is even, to the left if the starting number of pieces is odd). If there is no tower position in the chosen direction, move the piece to the opposite end, but then continue to move in the correct direction")* and then show that always works

Comment: As for your second question, you in effect move every disk from A to C, and then (after jumping one instruction because there is no legal move) continuing has the effect of moves every disk from C to B, and if you went on again would move every disk from B to A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested, I explain how to solve the Tower of Hanoi (plus induction proofs) in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G70ctw9ILVI).

The Iterative Solution basically relies on the principle of induction. If you know how to move a tower with $n-1$ pieces then you can figure out how to move a tower with $n$ pieces. The solution is basically

1. Move $n-1$ pieces from pole A to pole C
2. Move the remaining disk on pole A to pole B
3. Move the $n-1$ tower you left on pole C back on top of pole B

Of course step 1) is much more involved than the other steps! Let's unroll step 1) and see what patterns we notice.

1. Move the $n-2$ pieces from pole A to pole B
2. Move the $n-1$ disk that's left on pole A to pole C
3. Move the $n-2$ tower from pole B onto pole C
4. Move the remaining disk on pole A to pole B
5. Move the $n-1$ tower you left on pole C back on top of pole B

Aside from step 1), the other steps involve moving a single disk (the only legal move) at a time between the poles in a pattern indicated by the iterative solution. This pattern is
$$
A\rightarrow B\\
A\rightarrow C\\
B\rightarrow C\\
A\rightarrow B\\
C\rightarrow A\\
C\rightarrow B
$$

If we completely unroll step 1), then we see that the full move sequence for solving the Towers of Hanoi is just repeating this pattern of $6$ steps over and over until we are done. Of course, if we want the tower to end up on a specific pole, we may have to reorder the $6$ steps depending on if the initial tower has an even or an odd number of disks.